# Calendar validation with Bootstrap validator

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, bootstrapvalidator

I want that when selecting a date `x`, I change the time. That is to say if for `Monday` I have from `12 pm` to `6 pm` that when I choose `Sunday` I leave from `12 pm` to `10 pm`.

Not necessarily those example days. I want to make them with any specific date. I'm using bootstrap and I only manage to deactivate specific dates with this.

```
$ (". form_datetime"). datetimepicker ({
    format: "dd MM yyyy - HH: ii P",
    language: 'is',
    startDate: '01 / 01/2018 12:00 PM ',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
    showMeridian: true,
    minuteStep: 30,
    autoclose: true,
    hoursDisabled: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,22,23',
    datesDisabled: ['25 -12-2018 - HH: ii P ',' 31-12-2018 - HH: ii P ',' 01-01-2019 - HH: ii P '],
});
```

I block the hours that I want from the clock in general, and I block the dates that I want in general, but when I want to block an hour that is part of a specific date, it does not give me.

I have the date and time on the same `datetimepicker`. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Spam question https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Deleted non-English